# Adobe Air Javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, air

Alright, I feel like this is a stupid question but I literally cannot find the API for Adobe AIR Javascript on Google. I'm trying to gain access to the filesystem and network etc, but everything I find doesn't really seem to give me anything more than ActionScript redirects. Anyone know of a place with the full API?

Comment: Please be more clear. Adobe AIR is a Runtime.
You can develop RIAs using ADT either using JavaScript or ActionScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Getting started](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/getting_started_air_js.html)
- [API manual / tutorials](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/index.html)
- [API reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/index.html#top)

Apparently they call it the "HTML" or "AJAX" API.