# "Installable" web-app with Adobe Air?

Tags: air

I have a website that would ideally be accessed by users who have downloaded and installed it as "software"...  I know i can create an "Application Shortcut" in Google Chrome to allow me to access my web-app in a window that does not resemble a web-browser (i love this by the way and it would work perfectly if it did not require a full install of Chrome).  The problem is that i am not sure of a way to re-distribute GoogleChrome with a pre-configured application shortcut like this.  I have also read a bit about Mozilla Prism which seems similar.  After reading over some options, it looks like AdobeAIR is my best bet.  I have not yet worked with it, but it looks like I can create a downloadable executable that will contain a web-based interface.  This seems ideal, but all the documentation i have read thus far seems to make it sound like all the resources need to be locally included within the distribution.  Can i just create an "empty" AdobeAIR frame that contains my live (server) website?  Having never worked with AIR, is this reasonably easy to do (just a matter of setting up an iframe or something)?  I do not want any content stored locally on teh user's computer, as it is a constantly changing data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIR has [badge](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_badge_install.html) installation option, and you can [author content in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616473/adobe-air-javascript-api) for it. There is also full-featured browser control in AIR (webkit-based), so it seems AIR has everything you need.

Comment: not sure this really answers the main question.  Can i just create an "empty" AdobeAIR frame that contains my live (server) website? Having never worked with AIR, is this reasonably easy to do (just a matter of setting up an iframe or something)?

Comment: Setting up mx:HTML control and point it to site you need should be easy enough (maybe even simpler with JS api, I used to work with ActionScript.)