# Adobe AIR: JavaScript and ActionScript together?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

We are creating an `AIR application`. Since AIR applications can be created by using both `ActionScript 3` or `JavaScript/HTML`, we started developing the app with JS/HTML. But we felt that some parts of the app can be better implemented using ActionScript.

> The question is: Is it possible to combine these two under the same
>   application (calling JS functions in ActionScript and vice versa)?
>
> Also, we need to have a system tray icon for our app. Which platform
>   can this be better implemented with: JS or AS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing the application in HTML/JS there is a Javascript API for Adobe Air which exposes the functionality for Adobe Air via method calls in Javascript.

This would allow you such things as System Tray / Toasters / FileSystem access all through Javascript.

[This question on the Adobe Air Javascript APi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616473/adobe-air-javascript-api) gives you links to the documentation.